# 250v rated glass fuse on 12V

Tags: fuses

I have assembled an audio amplifier, starting from a cheap tpa3116d2 circuit board. It is powered up by using another cheap step-up circuit to reach 14V (manufacturer suggested 24V).
I wanted to dissipate any potential heat by adding a (oversized) vent to the circuit.
Both the amplifier + step-up are supplied by a 12v PSU from an old desktop pc.

To feel safe that this setup wouldn't burn my house, I had decided to add a fuse on the +12V line between the PSU and the vent+stepup circuit, on a small prototype PCB. I had placed it the closest I could to the 12v connector.

I had some 250V rated glass fuses, I had found (by trial and error) that the 0.5A glass fuse does its job (the 0.25A fused as soon as I have turned on the amplifier), and it has protected the speakers from a overcurrent spike by opening the circuit (the amplifier does not turn on properly when the volume is set to high on boot).
Do I have to worry about the fact that the glass fuses are 250V and not 12v rated? Are there any factors to take into account when considering fuses?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to worry about the fact that the glass fuses are 250V and not 12v rated?

No. 250V AC fuses are okay for up to 60V DC.

Comment: But also check the PSU rating on the 12V supply - if it’s fused at 1A it should be capable of 1A (which for a PC supply is very likely).  At very high current there’s a possibility of exceeding the breaking capacity of the fuse - even when the fuse wire has burned away completely the fuse can continue to arc across the terminals, but this is likely to happen at around 1000A.  I’ve seen it happen and it’s quite exciting.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Is it a rule of thumb?

Comment: It's a rule of thumb. But on second thought, it will more likely be a 250V DC fuse to begin with.